# Finding specific values and replacing them by others. Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, for-loop, numpy

I am very new to programming. I have code in matlab:

```
x2(x2>=0)=1; 
x2(x2<0)=-1; 
%Find values in x2 which are less than 0 and replace them with -1, 
%where x2 is an array like

0,000266987932788242
0,000106735120804439
-0,000133516844874253
-0,000534018243439120
```

I tried to do this in Python using code

```
if x2>=0:
   x2=1
if x2<0:
   x2=-1
```

This returns ***ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()***

How should I do it so that I get all the positive replaced by ***1*** and negatives by ***-1*** and ***STORE*** all of this in the ***x2*** for example, not just print, so that I could use it later to do some other stuff.

Comment: Updated my answer now. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

```
x2 = [0.000266987932788242, 0.000106735120804439, -0.000133516844874253, -0.000534018243439120]
print [1 if num >= 0 else num for num in x2]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, -0.000133516844874253, -0.000534018243439120]
```

Second:

```
x2 = [-1, 2, -3, 4]
print [-1 if num < 0 else num for num in x2]
```

**Output**

```
[0.000266987932788242, 0.000106735120804439,  -1, -1]
```

**If you need both of them in a single statement**

```
x2 = [0.000266987932788242, 0.000106735120804439, -0.000133516844874253, -0.000534018243439120]
x2 = [-1 if num < 0 else 1 for num in x2]
print x2
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's ability to index over boolean array.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-5.3, -0.4, 0.6, 5.4, 0.0])

not_neg = x >= 0 # creates a boolean array

x[not_neg] = 1 # index over boolean array
x[~not_neg] = -1
```

Result:

```
>>> x
array([-1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: The last line can just be `x[~not_neg] = -1`.